# getFieldDecorator rules for password reset?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying to do a "field 2 does not match field 1" thing here (i.e. "passwords do not match).

There [isn't much documentation](https://ant.design/components/form/) on the available rules for the antd forms. They point at this project [here](https://github.com/yiminghe/async-validator#rules).

Below is my current form:

```
const ResetPasswordForm = Form.create()(React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      loading: false
    };
  },
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (err) {
        failure();
      }
      if (!err) {
        let newPassword = values.newPassword;
        let repeatNewPassword = values.repeatNewPassword;
        handleResetPassword(newPassword, repeatNewPassword, this.props.token);
      }
    });

  },
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;

    const newPasswordRules = [
      { required: true, message: 'Please input a new password!' }
    ];

    const repeatNewPassword = [
      { required: true, message: 'Please repeat the new password!' }
    ];

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('newPassword', { rules: newPasswordRules })(
            <Input addonBefore={<Icon type="lock" />} type="password" placeholder="New password" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('repeatNewPassword', { rules: repeatNewPassword })(
            <Input addonBefore={<Icon type="lock" />} type="password" placeholder="Repeat new password" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          <Button loading={this.state.loading} type="primary" htmlType="submit" className={css(styles.loginButton)}>
            Reset Password
          </Button>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}));
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction for creating a rule that checks that the first field value matches the second, that'd be awesome!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find it in this register form demo: https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-register

Answer (score 8):

Please, follow these lines:

```
  <Form.Item
    name="password"
    label="Password"
    rules={[
      {
        required: true,
        message: 'Please input your password!',
      },
    ]}
    hasFeedback
  >
    <Input.Password />
  </Form.Item>

  <Form.Item
    name="confirm"
    label="Confirm Password"
    dependencies={['password']}
    hasFeedback
    rules={[
      {
        required: true,
        message: 'Please confirm your password!',
      },
      ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
        validator(rule, value) {
          if (!value || getFieldValue('password') === value) {
            return Promise.resolve();
          }
          return Promise.reject('The two passwords that you entered do not match!');
        },
      }),
    ]}
  >
    <Input.Password />
  </Form.Item>
```